# Programatically open Outlook draft message for further editing

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS in a command-line tool to create a Draft in the user's Inbox using EmailMessage.Save().

The user should further edit the newly created draft email and then send it.

How can I make Oulook (2013) open the draft for further editing?  I already have from EWS the EmailMessage id for the draft in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is you can register the Outlook protocol see https://www.slipstick.com/problems/outlook-missing-outlook-protocol/ and then convert the EWSId to a EntryId using the EWS convertId operation. Then you should be able to open the item in Outlook using Outlook:// + the HexEntryId you get back from convertId.